# What to do when users are offended

Tags: discussion, downvotes, comments, users

I'm just trying to understand the model SO:

- Why user does not want to explain own answer! we can not use the comments to discuss **about the problem** ? **only** put downvote ?

Help Center:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

**seriously ?** to me say the opposite ~ **we can't** use the comments to discuss about the problem

*see below all comment...*

---

I know better than to miss of inadequate people :)

anyway, what's the problem:

the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24580344/620351) from user [FuzzyTree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574819/fuzzytree)

- Author **ignored all** attention about problem with this answer - all users may misunderstand for own projects!
- Pushed votedown for me because he might offended for constructive notice! **not commented**! **not dialogue!**
- Flagged to deleted my last comment - yes, i know this is not constructive for solution... but where write it ..

what is that a kindergarten ? what did I do wrong ?!

my last comment was:

> if you think is your variant is safest and this problem not exist, write here - for constructive dialogue! 
>   However you only ignored my notice and pushed votedown for me... I know it's you :) what's the problem ?
>   you have time to answer on other questions, but not for comment for problem with your variant ?

User does **not respond** ! and does **not comment on anything** !

**General question**: What SO proposes in this case ?

*for detail see all [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580287/insert-only-if-there-is-no-duplicate-already-mysql-php-pdo)*

*FuzzyTree **only** downvoted me ! does not respond ! and does not comment on anything ..*

---

**Solution from SO-community:**

- you should downvoted all answer who Dislike you !

---

**My Conclusion:**

I think I'm not interested in further participation in the SO as the answerer - it's not a problem of reputation (for those **who did not** understand).

This is a problem in relation to people who are resent for constructive comments and behave like a little children! And others has support of this behavior..

Contrary to what is written in [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)! *dialogues should not to be - you mean*

It's really problem for answer what can be used in real projects! who will fix bugs in 3rd party code ? if we can not use the comments to discuss about all the problem... I can mistake also! then write to me about what's going on ... we are all humans, but you support misbehavior of users

I think it not will be interesting for me to waste own time. However, I enjoy helping people :) but... *it's crazy for me* о_о *really*

Everyone who has tried to understand the situation - Respect! thanks for watching ., and see you later.

Comment: For the record, they did not delete your comment (nor would they have the ability to). A moderator removed that when it was flagged as being not constructive, because frankly it wasn't. You don't know for sure that they downvoted your answer. You've stated what you believe to be wrong with the answer, and provided your own. That's all you can do here.

Comment: @BradLarson I know about flag, I wrote `i know this is not constructive for solution` (I mean this deleted as a unconstructive, and I agree!) 
`You don't know for sure that they downvoted`, yes, only guesses - time + activity + change reputation 5,340 -> 5,338 -> 5,337 + answer... 
and most importantly: he does not comment on anything after my votedown for him..he is silent.. - that's all history /who moderator, you can see...

Comment: I understand about employment. I am also working man!! I saw **he has activity** with another question + he answered **2** day ago. What's the problem of SO ? I can't' believe it ... 
or I don't votedown but he is ?? or ok! if he's contacted with me or commented... but no... . **he is silent**
I also understand about mistakes... **anything can happen**! **But** he is silent and not contacted! I always go for a constructive dialogue but **he is silent** What's the problem ? tell me please !

Comment: The problem is that you are making a massive assumption about what happened, and you have zero proof.  Downvotes are anonymous *by design*.  Whoever downvoted you is silent because they chose to be.

Comment: @fbueckert yes, you right, i have only [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262775/what-to-do-when-users-are-offended#comment54263_262775) information, you won.

Comment: That's still a massive assumption.  They may have downvoted something, but you have no concrete proof whatsoever.  And attempting to rationalize who did what is an exercise in futility.

Comment: Can't tell if this is a trick question. The user being offended appears to be the one asking this question.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm just trying **to understand the model SO** I'm here as 'answer' only 43 days (account >3 year ago)
and then a question - why should I waste **my time** to help for "being offended" **as result** ? **points** ? you really think ?

Comment: @fbueckert bonus, see my [profile on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/620351/reg) and try to guess - who has my voteup.. hard ? but you of course right, it's my guess.. 
But the **user does not want to explain own answer**! **It's not model SO** ? tell me ? because I can mistake also! dialogue should not be ? **right ?**

Comment: bonus2: these answer can be used in real projects! who will fix bugs in 3rd party code ? if **we can not use the comments to discuss about the problem** ...

Comment: I feel your pain, although we can't be sure if he actually was the person who downvoted you.

You just have to accept that some people will downvote for the wrong reasons.  Not everyone behaves like an adult, you just have to accept it and move on.

Comment: @DoctorJones Thanks for comment. `..and move on` - already :) _walk, tea, coffee, etc._

Also note: it's question also not about punishment for concrete user, of course! only about dialogue - as it should be to solve problems... **is not it** ? my friends ...
otherwise it's really very unpleasant -_- 

but ~60/40 guys have in mind - "communication should not be" - this is what scares... but, everyone has own right choice.

Comment: This always happens when power is given to general public. People just spam upvotes or downvotes. Just use this websites to look for answers, leave the system to the "self-employed" caretakers of the planet. lmao

Comment: the main problem not with downvotes(without explanation - it's really not so good. I recommend to add a short required descr when it down like descr for git, but anyway that's not the point).the problem is who supports this behavior(no, really protects this) |`Just use...` already :) look my profile.But! anyway I still support all my old answers/questions! Because I'm responsible for my own solutions/advices unlike most <_< btw a few days ago I updated profile descr, just my thoughts about this place. hmm, the short meaning "who care", just numbers.Thanks to all who understood what's going on.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> General question: What SO proposes in this case?

Let it go...

Take a break, take a walk, have a cup of coffee, or a pint.

You voiced your concern and it is noted in the comments under the answer. Users who see the post in the future will also see your comments about a potential problem with the answer.

The other user has no obligation to edit their answer to address your concerns.

Comment: :) yes, I also think... but he downvoted me ! does not respond ! and does not comment on anything ... mean that is normal practice for SO, Right ?! anyway, thanks!

Comment: @reg We all get into [one of these](http://xkcd.com/386/) once in a while, try not to let it get to you.

Comment: @reg please also remember that not everybody is logged in to SO all the time. If their boss is standing behind them, or their mother-in-law is visiting, responding to you may not be their first priority.

Comment: @DNA guys! I understood! you are not understanding what's the problem :(  you can see the activity user for example... 
...mean it's realy funny... for downvote he has a time ? at same time! How about rule of SO ? How I can a new answers after this ?!

Comment: @reg, so what? What do you expect? That a moderator goes to his house and *force* him to respond to you? *You* are the only one that can do something and that is: **nothing**. =P

Comment: mean..you taking things **too seriously**. @brasofilo if I set down for your all answer&question simple out of boredom or because dislike you... you will not have a some question ? why - for example...

Comment: @reg, I could say the same... The general opinion from other users is that you already did all the best you could, and there's nothing else you or anybody can do. Well, there's something, as *apaul34208* said: drink a beer (pint) ;)

Comment: [privileges - vote-down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) / @brasofilo `drink a beer (pint) ;)` already :)

Comment: @reg, cool, tomorrow is another day, bye and best wishes.

Comment: @brasofilo thanks! Same to you!

Comment: @apaul34208 I only read the first line and I thought you were going to recite the "Let It Go" song lol.